# Not getting anything back from sqlsrv_num_rows

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying pull back data from MS SQL via a php page. I have got a valid connection, and am trying a simple SELECT * FROM MyTable but sqlsrv_num_rows is just blank no matter what I do!!!

Here is my code:

```
    function connect() {

    $serverName = DB_HOST; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>DB_NAME, "UID"=>DB_USER, "PWD"=>DB_PASSWORD);
    $this->connection = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


    if( $this->connection ) {
         echo "<br>Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "<br>Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }       


}
```

The echo for Connection established is working so all AOK there!

Now when I do a simple query:

```
    function query($sql) {
    if ($this->debug) {
        echo $sql . "<br />";
    }       
    $this->sql = $sql;
    $this->recordset = sqlsrv_query($this->connection, $sql);

    if (!$this->recordset) {
        die('<br><br>Invalid query :<br><br><bold>' . $this->sql . '</bold><br><br>' . sqlsrv_errors());
    }

    echo "<br>rows = " . sqlsrv_num_rows($this->recordset);
```

I get absolutely nothing from the above echo? Any reason why? Or can you suggest a new echo I can try to debug this?

All my code in my DB class is converted from mysql so there may be a few bits wrong that is doing the damage!

I've even tried a super simple version, all the code together and it's still blank/false:

```
    $server = DB_HOST;
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, array( "Database"=>DB_NAME, "UID"=>DB_USER, "PWD"=>DB_PASSWORD) );
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM MyTable");
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
echo "<br>row count = " . $row_count;
if ($row_count === false)
  echo "\nerror\n";
else if ($row_count >=0)
  echo "\n$row_count\n";
  die;
```

Comment: Can we see the contents of $sql?

Comment: Sorry I have fixed it now, it needs $options adding to the query:

Found the answer immediately after posting!

You need this in your query code:

            $this->sql = $sql;
  $params = array();
  $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );  
        $this->recordset = sqlsrv_query($this->connection, $sql, $params, $options);


"SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET
 

Lets you access rows in any order. However, a keyset cursor does not update the row count if a row is deleted from the table (a deleted row is returned with no values).

keyset is the abbreviated form of SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET."

Comment: feel free to post your own answer ;-)

Comment: what volkerk said, post it as an answer and accept it, that way anyone searching can quickly see that a solution was found

Answer (score 14):

Try this.....

Replace below statement

```
sqlsrv_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM MyTable");
```

as

```
sqlsrv_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM MyTable", array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered"));
```

Comment: Some explanation must be required! It helps to understand better rader than copypaste. :)